# Loading 2 react apps together in a single page. Only single app is visible

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have 2 react apps, which I want to load in a single page. How could I do this? Each of my react app is currently running on a Apache server. So I was trying to render the app using my proxy nodejs service, which I have described as follows. All it does is download the 2 apps (react build) and send the HTML back to the browser. But the problem is that, only single app is visible. What could be the reason for this?

```
app.get('/', async (req, resp, next) => {
    try {
        let urlList = [
            'http://localhost/controller',
            'http://localhost/display'
        ];

        let combined = await Promise.map(urlList, (url) => axios(url).catch(err => false));
        combined = combined.filter(Boolean);
        if (combined.length == 0) {
            // React app not started!
            resp.json({
                status: false,
                message: 'None of the application is running'
            });
        } else {
            resp.send(`<div><div id='app1'>${combined[1].data}</div><div id='app2'>${combined[0].data}</div></div>`)
                .end();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        resp.json({
            status: false,
            message: err.message
        });
    }
});
```

This is how I had created the apps:

- npx create-react-app controller
- npx create-react-app display

Then I build the apps and placed it into the apache root. The above nodejs script, attempts to download the pages and send the HTML of both the apps to the browser. Only the first app with `id = app1` is visible.

[image]

Comment: The approach you're taking is uncommon and likely not going to be scalable. If they are separate applications with separate functionality, then they should be separated to their own service. However, if they are reliant upon each other, then you should have a single app with supporting microservices that communicate via an API. For example, Netflix is considered a single app with hundreds of microservices: https://medium.com/refraction-tech-everything/how-netflix-works-the-hugely-simplified-complex-stuff-that-happens-every-time-you-hit-play-3a40c9be254b

Comment: In laymans terms, if `app1` and `app2` are independent, then you would have `app1.domain.com` and `app2.domain.com`, otherwise you would just have `app.domain.com` with `service1` and `service2` communicating with each other to serve a single app